# Calling a function from an .ERL to .YAWS file

Tags: erlang, yaws

I am very new to YAWS and ERLANG and would like to call a function from a different .erl file to the YAWS page.

i.e.      I have a page called webpage.yaws   and have another file called utilities.erl and would like to call a function from utilities.erl in webpage.yaws

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very simple, just call the function like you would normally do in Erlang programs, i.e. `Module:func_name(arguments)` the only thing you need to do is make sure Yaws knows where to find the compiled BEAM file. In the Yaws configuration file add:

```
ebin_dir = /tmp/ebin
```

Compile your `utilities.erl`, put the BEAM file in `/tmp/ebin` and you can call your utility functions from the `webpage.yaws` file.

Full example:

**website.yaws**:

```
 <html>
  <erl>
    out(Arg) ->
       D=utilities:get_some_strings(),
       {html, ["Retrieved from utilities: ", D]}.
  </erl>    
 </html>
```

**utilities.erl**:

```
-module(utilities).

-export([get_some_strings/0]).

get_some_strings() ->
    "hello world!".
```

Comment: I am also a newbie to Erlang. So I am not sure if I am interpreting something wrong or picking a fine point. I liked johlo's answer but I could only get it to load a function in a module defined in a beam file *after* I restarted the yaws service